# Finding quadratic root?

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, polynomials, cubics

Is there a way to find a missing cubic root if a maximum turning point and a turning point on the x axis is known? The maximum turning point is at (50,30) while the turning point root is (100,0)

So in this equation

F(x) = (x+a)(x-100)(x-100)

I need to find knowing that the given points are stat points with a gradient of zero.

Thank you

Comment: Sorry I meant to say I need to find the value of A

Comment: Hint: Compute $a$ from $F(50)=125000+2500a=30$

Comment: I don't understand that?

Comment: You do not understand **what**?

Answer (score 0):

In the answer to [Finding cubic function from points?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1982690/115115), you already were given the full factorization leading to the third root at $x=25$.

In your product you are missing the overall scaling factor, as the extremal point $(50,30)$ imposes two conditions necessitating two degrees of freedom.